# External authentication in Plone 4 (RADIUS, local script)?

Tags: authentication, plone

I'm looking for an easy way to enable external authentication for Plone 4 site, it can be RADIUS or local script. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication in plone is provided by PAS plugin . You have a good documentation about that on plone.org at documentation/manual/plone-community-developer-documentation/members/pluggable-authentication-service/index

You must implements authentication plugin to do the job (Extraction Plugins  and Authentication Plugins I think).

You have example on collective : https://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/PASPlugins/ of PASPlugins.

For example PASPlugins/apachepas/trunk/auth.py implements an authentification based on http header (X_REMOTE_USER) send by apache  (extraction plugin and authentification plugin) (you can see doctest to see how it work /PASPlugins/apachepas/trunk/apachepas.txt)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like such a plugin has already been written:
  http://www.zope.org/Members/shimizukawa/PASRadius